# Using Barcodes as ID cards

Tags: python, camera

I am thinking of using a barcode reader with barcodes on cards of paper to use as ID cards. The barcodes will be read using the raspberry pi's camera with some image processing software (using the following guide : https://technoobsite.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/raspberry-pi-barcode-scanner/) to convert the cameras output into numbers that i can then process in python.

My Question is that can anyone who has had experience in this subject find anything wrong with what i want to do or any better way to do what i want to do. All i need for the system to do is output a string of numbers that i can then use in python later on to log that ID card in / out of another system. It doesn't even have to be using barcodes but this seems to be the most cost effective way of performing the task that i want to do without using a mouse / keyboard.

Comment: have you considered using a bar code reader? though, if you already have the camera and know how to use it to read barcodes, then I can't see anything wrong with doing so

Comment: you can buy a barcode scanner that plugs into a USB port and emulates a keyboard .... some scanners have programmable prefix and postfix characters .... most of them will append a newline character after the barcode characters